# can't print the names in the right order and the sum of profit is wrong as well

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

```sql
CREATE TABLE seller_details
(
    seller_id integer PRIMARY KEY, 
    seller_name text
);

CREATE TABLE sales_data
(
    seller_id integer, 
    quantity integer, 
    price_per_item integer
);

INSERT INTO seller_details VALUES (1, 'sam');
INSERT INTO seller_details VALUES (2, 'jack');
INSERT INTO seller_details VALUES (3, 'john');

INSERT INTO sales_data VALUES (1, 4, 100);
INSERT INTO sales_data VALUES (1, 5, 200);
INSERT INTO sales_data VALUES (1, 4, 300);
INSERT INTO sales_data VALUES (2, 2, 500);
INSERT INTO sales_data VALUES (2, 9, 300);
INSERT INTO sales_data VALUES (3, 1, 500);

COMMIT;


SELECT * FROM seller_details;
SELECT * FROM sales_data;

SELECT
    seller_name, 
    (quantity * price_per_item) AS total_sales 
FROM
    seller_details sd, sales_data sda
GROUP BY
    seller_name
ORDER BY
    total_sales DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.. Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. See edit help re code blocks. Please put your question in the post body, not just the title.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: i need to get the output table from my query, but i can not get it and i'm trying it from last 2-3 hours this is the closest i have reached - SELECT distinct salesman.name, sum(quant * price) as total_sales
FROM salesman , salesdata
group by salesdata.id,name
order by total_sales desc

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Click on "edit". PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `sum` from `(quantity*price_per_item) as total_sales` in your aggregation, however your real issue is how you have done your join on the tables. Your query is creating a cross join (see below) instead of an inner join i.e. you are generation more records and not based on a matched seller id. I recommend specifying the type of joins in the future

The query below makes these adjustments

```sql
select seller_name, SUM(quantity*price_per_item) as total_sales 
from seller_details sd
inner join sales_data sda ON sd.seller_id = sda.seller_id
group by seller_name
order by total_sales desc
```

| seller_name | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| jack | 3700 |
| sam | 2600 |
| john | 500 |

---

[View Demo DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xpHFvUapNPY5kdACRnqqoj/0)

I've included a demo of the cross join results received below for your perusal. When summed, these would give you greater total_sales than desired.

```sql
select seller_name, quantity*price_per_item as total_sales 
from seller_details sd,sales_data sda 
order by seller_name
```

| seller_name | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| jack | 400 |
| jack | 1000 |
| jack | 1200 |
| jack | 1000 |
| jack | 2700 |
| jack | 500 |
| john | 400 |
| john | 1000 |
| john | 1200 |
| john | 1000 |
| john | 2700 |
| john | 500 |
| sam | 400 |
| sam | 1000 |
| sam | 1200 |
| sam | 1000 |
| sam | 2700 |
| sam | 500 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xpHFvUapNPY5kdACRnqqoj/1)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks, this was really helpful, i got it now, i was confused with the joins. very well explained! Thanks again man